# Overlay canvas on a div with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website there is a `<div>` with some css styled rings in it. It's like the android unlock pattern. 9 dots which can be connected in different ways. I want to overlay a canvas on this, so that I can measure the drawing the user makes and color in the touched dots accordingly. What's the best way to overlay this?

Comment: Why do you need a canvas to do that? Can you not set some CSS to the styled rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways as far as I can see

1) use another nested div with a no background set so its transparent.  Then inherit the parents dimensions in the CSS

```
<div id='rings'>
   <div id='overlay'>

   </div>
</div>
```

css-
     #rings
     {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
     }

```
 #rings div#overlay
 {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
 }
```

2) or create a seperate, absolutely positioned DIV and use z-index in the CSS to overlay it

```
<div id='rings'>

</div>

<div id='overlay'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `{ position: relative; }` to your `div`, and `{ position: absolute; }` to your `canvas`. Make sure your canvas is a child element of your div. Next, give your canvas the same size as your div, and there you have a canvas overlay where you can draw everything.
By the way, canvases have transparent background by default, so it's like putting a transparent plastic paper on top of your div, where you can draw all your graphics ( lines like in android i suppose.
As for the circles, you can style those by css.

Comment: Thanks, but now the canvas drawing disappears behind the rings. As can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hfmBG